# Randomly getting - - ms - - from appium server

Tags: appium

Can anyone tell when does this occur in the Appium Logs: **- - ms - -**

`2017-07-01 10:11:49:851 - info: [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/f0959bfd-0901-4613-81e1-584ad58d163f/element/15/value - - ms - -`

I am getting this in the logs randomly, and whenever i get this, the Selenium Hub says `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [f0959bfd-0901-4613-81e1-584ad58d163f] was terminated due to FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED`

More appium server logs can be found here: https://pastebin.com/B4syZHF2

Comment: Which selenium version you are using as this issue is fixed in selenium 2.43

Comment: selenium 3.0.1, appium java-client-5.0.0-BETA3. This has nothing to do with core Appium, Java or WDA versions. I have another setup which runs just fine. I have matched the versions and even tried to replace the whole Appium node_module folder. This is something else, that depends more on other executables, which i am unable to distinguish between the working and the non working mac-minis. 

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/8814